# Standardized residual in Pearson Independence Test

Tags: regression, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, residuals

Considering a $I×J$ contingency table, a Pearson chi-square statistic to test the independence is given by:
$$Χ ^2 = Σ_{ij} \frac{(n_{ij} - \mu_{ij})^2}{\mu_{ij}} $$
And the Pearson residual is:
$$e_i = \frac{(n_i - \mu_i)}{\sqrt\mu_i}$$
Which has a variance $Var(e_i) \leq 1$.

According to S. J. Haberman's paper in 1973, a standardized residual which has standardized variance is:
$$\lambda_i = \frac{(n_i - \mu_i)}{\sqrt{\mu_i(1-p_{i+})(1-p_{+j})}}$$

My problem is, why is this true? In other words, why the asymptotic variance $Var(e_{ij}) = (1-p_{i+})(1-p_{+j})$ is true?

Also, I believe this is related to the residual analysis in linear regression, where it is given by $e^* = \frac{e}{\sqrt(1-h)}$. My guess is, maybe this problem can be proved by transforming it into a regression model. But so far I'm stuck.